# Accessing user feed using Facebook Graph API v2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I recently created an app in Facebook. By default the API version used was v2.0. Thus for every new user it generated a 'App-scoped User ID'. I am retrieving the ids of users through the graph api search feature.

Now I want to use the /{user-id}/feed to fetch feed of a specific user.

Is there a way I can access a specific user's feed using an access token generated for my Facebook account through a Facebook app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page** and **User** is different thing. For page, you can access **PAGE_ID/feed** easily with App Access Token if this post is not restriced (age, gender...etc).If the post is restricted, then you must use User access token to access this posts.

For user is different story, Facebook is very strict on user feed. So you must use User access token to get **User_ID/feed**.

I suggest you to do like that way:

1. If the user is your app user authorized with **read_stream** permission, then you access the **USER_ID/feed**. It's because **USER_ID/feed** endpoint only available if user give permission **read_stream** to your app. App Access Token is not allow.
2. If the user is not your app user with **read_stream**, then you access the **USER_ID/links** instead. It's because no **read_stream** permission require to access this endpoint. App Access Token is not allow.
3. If this is a page, then you access the **PAGE_ID/feed**(better) or **PAGE_ID/links**. App Access Token is allow except restricted posts. So it's better to use User Access Token.

As document stated:

> Any valid access token is required to view public links.

This statement is wrong and misleading because App Access Token may able to read **PAGE_ID/links**(non-restricted post) but it can't read the **USER_ID/links** endpoint.

Theres's some other variant endpoints, e.g. USER_ID/statuses, in which:

1. App access token not allow.
2. If the user A **did not give permission** user_status to app X, then (App X)**User A** Access Token access user_A_ID/statuses will only return status type posts **post via app X**.
3. If the user A **did give permission** user_status to app X, then (App X)**User A** Access Token access user_A_ID/statuses will return **all status type** posts **without app restriction**.
4. If the user A **did not give permission** user_status to app X, then (App X)**User B** Access Token access user_A_ID/statuses will **not return any data**.
5. If the user A **did give permission** user_status to app X, then (App X)**User B** Access Token access user_A_ID/statuses will return **all status type** posts **without app restriction** which was **public**.

**Update:**
Facebook API changed again and now USER_ID/links only accessible for the same app user id.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is possible with Graph API v2.0 Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#readperms

Quote:

> - **Any valid access token** is required **to view public links**.
> - A **user access token with read_stream permission** is required.
> - **Only posts whose authors have also granted read_stream permission to the app will be shown.**

Comment: Is there any other way I can access public posts of users? I know FQL allows a user to read public posts without user_access_tokens. Since FQL does not require user_access_tokens with read_stream permission, is there a way I can use the app-scoped user-id with FQL?

Comment: That's not true that FQL allows what you describe. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/ Try to access the CocaCola page posts: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+post_id,message+from+stream+where+source_id=40796308305

Comment: Ya but I can access the CocaCola page posts using an app generated access token. Its just that I am not able to use the app-scoped user ids in the FQL which I get upon using the graph api search feature. Is there a way I can use the app-scoped user ids with an app access token to access public posts using sql?

Comment: I don't think that you can access public page posts (from the page itself) with just an app access token. Doesn't work for me: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+post_id,message,created_time+from+stream+where+source_id=40796308305+and+actor_id=40796308305&access_token=

Comment: The link that you used does not have a value for the access_token parameter. I created an app in Facebook through which I generated an access token for my account. I can access the public posts on the Coca Cola page using the generated access token. Only problem is its a page whereas I want to access user's public posts. Graph API v2.0 generates user-scoped-ids for users which I am not able to use with FQL.

Comment: Do you think I paste my app access token to a publically available site like SO? I'm confused that you now use a user access token again, before you said this works with non-user access tokens. Use `{app_id}|{app_secret}` as app access token and test again. Anyway, I think (and I stated already) that it's not possible what you want to achive. I'm out