# Facebook Graph API {user-id}/feed from others empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to get `/{user-id}/feed` from another user (user B) rather than "me" (user A), but the query returns an empty list.

I'm using the **Graph API Explorer** to make the queries, and I've got the Access Token with `user_posts`, `user_status` and `read_stream` permissions, but I can't get this information.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472324/3708095) is said that:

> Additionally the queried user needs to grant the app the read_stream permission.

In [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909379/3708095) they said:

> 1. If the user is your app user authorized with read_stream permission, then you access the USER_ID/feed. It's because USER_ID/feed endpoint only available if user give permission read_stream to your app. App Access Token is not allow.
> 2. If the user is not your app user with read_stream, then you access the USER_ID/links instead. It's because no read_stream permission require to access this endpoint. App Access Token is not allow.

MY QUESTIONS:

1. Do I really need this other user (user B) to grant this permission to access his feed?
2. Where can I find official documentation saying so?
3. As `/{user-id}/links` seems to be accessible, are `posts`, `statuses` or `tagged` accessible too, or I just can access `links` without User B granting this permission?

**Note:**
Since the purpose is to use it in and iOS and Android App I can't use the `read_stream` permission, so I would use the `user_posts` which is supposed to be valid as they say in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed
>

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course, why would anyone want your App to access his newsfeed without his authorization? Keep in mind that not only the user would be able to access the feed of his friends, but the App too - which means, it would be easy for the App developer to get access.
2. Should be clear with number 1. Why would there even be a permission if you could just grab the feed from another user with it?
3. You can´t get ANY data from a user without his authorization, for privacy reasons. Friend permissions are gone.

Comment: Well, if I am a user of this app, and I'm already friend with User B, and I can see his posts on facebook... why couldn't I see them on the app (even if B doesn't have the app???)
Regarding to 3... So why am I getting results when I query for links?

Comment: that´s why you don´t get read_stream approved ;) - why would a friend of you want your app to get access to his stream, without his authorization? that just does not make sense. an app should get NOTHING about anyone (friend or not) without his authorization. about links: there´s something in the docs that public links can be returned.

Comment: _“Well, if I am a user of this app, and I'm already friend with User B, and I can see his posts on facebook... why couldn't I see them on the app”_ – because that would also divulge that information to a 3rd party – a.k.a. the app developer – and therefor it is of course B’s choice whether they want that to happen or not.

Comment: thanx, that´s a much better explanation than mine :)