# Azure Logic apps Facebook connector gives empty response

Tags: facebook, azure, facebook-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

When I try to use the Facebook connector in Azure logic apps I can't seem to get the "Get user timeline" to work.

I know for a fact that the User ID is valid (I checked using this URL: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=). I also know for sure that the user has posts on it's timeline. I also tried multiple user ID's.

When I open the failed request in the Logic app I get this, the response is empty every time.
[image]

Is this related to privacy settings? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: User ids are app-scoped since API v2.0. Meaning, you probably can’t just get an old, "global" user id from somewhere, and expect that to work - the connector is using a specific app id, and user ids must "belong" to that app. Ideally this should be implemented in a way that the user logs into the app, so that it automatically gets their app-scoped id at that point. “Copy&Paste your user id”-interfaces are broken.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So that means Azure isn't up to date? Maybe I should look into what options Azure logic apps has for Facebook apps.

Comment: Hi @Jayjay I forwarded this to the team owns Facebook connector to advise.

Comment: Thanks @DerekLi! Are there any updates yet on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should probably retire/remove that operation. It is not possible to retrieve the post from Facebook graph API for another user's timeline. It used to so that is why it is there.  Specifically, this post might be helpful: [Facebook Graph API {user-id}/feed from others empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289407/facebook-graph-api-user-id-feed-from-others-empty)
The connector calls the /{user-id}/feed API.  You can try out the behavior in the Facebook Graph explorer as well.  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/